# What is the setting in PHP that enables the connection limit?

Tags: php

I am setting up a website. I have PHP code that will run for long periods of time. When the code runs, it takes 1-2 hours to finish the process.

This script works great up to 6, and interestingly the 7th link is "pending" until the previous one is finished.

CPU & Ram and Disk stable.

I tried the following;

Change PHP limits:

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 200
pm.start_servers = 1
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 200
```

Change Apache Limits (I wrote these numbers very high on purpose, but it didn't work.):

```
FcgidConnectTimeout 5
FcgidMaxProcesses 1000000
FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 1000000
FcgidMaxRequestInMem 65536000000
FcgidMaxRequestLen 13107200000
```

PHP Version: 7.2

In chrome console this php showing "pending", apache error log and journal error log is empty, just white screen and wait until the other is finished. What else should I try?

Comment: read about session_write_close(), placing this on top of the script will enable you to run as many sessions as you want, 7th or onward request will not wait for previous script execution completion.

Comment: hello @Farhan, thanks for helping. But I try session_write_close and this not working too. Because this not can be close the session until the process is finished.

Comment: did you place this before your code starts?

Comment: I placed it at the top and at the end. So I tried both. But it didn't work at all. I'm not sure maybe I did it wrong? My last try, like `session_start();` at the top of the file and `session_write_close();` at the end of the file.